# How to make generic spring data JPA into separate JAR file and inject wherever we want. I have tried with but getting "No qualifying bean of type"

Tags: spring-data-jpa

[Attached design framework_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiTVZ.png)while try to class from JAR throwing error message Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Comment: We need a way more detailed an precise description of what you are doing, what you are expecting as a result, and what you are actually getting.

Comment: Actually doing creating reusable component. creating framework model for curd operation(transaction related), exception handling, common utility class. all together into one JAR and included the same all the spring boot microservice. i am extending or inject whatever method i want. I have done for using entitymanager(save,update,delete,namedquery,nativequery....so on) and succeed. But i am trying for JPARepository and it fails. what is expected result generic jparepositry and generic dao method(using entity manager) and generic exception handling... etc put it into one JAR and use it.

Comment: @JensSchauder, please help if you have idea design attached

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.